# Powershell to check if .exe is running, if it is running, send email, if it isn't close script

Tags: powershell

```
if(get-process | ?{$_.path -eq "C:\My exes\Test1.exe"}){
    #exe is running. Send email
}
```

Found the above on another thread, hoping somone can add in the email part?

Comment: take a look at [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.3) Microsoft says it's deprecated but has no replacement. For internal use it should be fine.

Comment: The linked post shows an advanced use of `Send-MailMessage`, which hopefully provides enough guidance. Note that `Send-MailMessage` is considered obsolete for security reasons, which may or may not be a problem in your case. One modern alternative is the third-party [`Send-MailKitMessage`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Send-MailKitMessage) cmdlet, which builds on the third-party [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library. If you still need assistance, create a _new_ question that shows a concrete attempt to send an email with either of these two cmdlets.